# Will cities in my region produce money, oil and resources etc. while building another city?

Tags: simcity-2013

The question explains itself. Will other cities in my region produce money, oil etc. while building another city in the same region?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. City simulation is entirely client side as stated in this [Rock Paper Shotgun](http://www.rockpapershotgun.com/2013/03/12/simcity-server-not-necessary/) interview.

> The servers are not handling any of the computation done to simulate
>   the city you are playing. They are still acting as servers, doing some
>   amount of computation to route messages of various types between both
>   players and cities. As well, they’re doing cloud storage of save
>   games, interfacing with Origin, and all of that. But for the game
>   itself? No, they’re not doing anything.

Comment: Furthermore you won't even get payments for selling utilities (power/water/etc). The stats of each city (free utilities/job levels/commuters/etc) is determined and then it's put into stasis.