# What happens to other cities in the same region when you are not playing them?

Tags: simcity-2013

Are all the other cities in the region frozen if you aren't currently playing them?

Could you potentially volunteer all the safety and garbage services from all the surrounding cities to the one you are playing then just switch them when you go to play another city?

Comment: [The answer to this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/109119/27134) seems to imply that you would be able to volunteer all of your services to a neighbouring city while you were building elsewhere, but I haven't tested it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cities you are not playing currently are frozen in time.  However, if you volunteer your services to another city, that city will be able to use them regardless of the city being active or not.  You can absolutely volunteer all of your services to one city, and then change those when you want to work on another city.

The only caveat here is that you have to have a road connection to that city in order to volunteer the vehicles.  So you cannot volunteer every vehicle in a region to one city.  Not all cities have direct connections.  It can be a bit annoying because you may not have a direct connection to a city that is right next door.

Also, when you volunteer your services to another city that you aren't playing, you get money from that city for the services.  I've not seen any situation where you pay money for services volunteered however.